# Add character strings in numeric dataframes and concatenate two string dataframes

Tags: r

I have got two numeric dataframes, df1 with log fold changes (LFC) and df2 with p-values.

```
df1 = data.frame(V1=c(1.2, 1.5, 0.3),
                 V2=c(0.5, 0.9, 1.1),
                 V3=c(-0.9, -1.5, -0.4))

df2 = data.frame(Y1=c(0.02, 0.005, 0.06),
                 Y2=c(0.05, 0.009, 0.01),
                 Y3=c(0.01, 0.001, 0.1))
```

and for some presentation purposes, I would like to add the prefix "LFC = " in df1, and the prefix "p = " in df2, such that I get the following:

```
df1

V1           V2           V3
LFC = 1.2    LFC = 0.5    LFC = -0.9
LFC = 1.5,   LFC = 0.9    LFC = -1.5
LFC = 0.3    LFC = 1.1    LFC = -0.4


df2

Y1           Y2            Y3
p = 0.02     p = 0.05      p = 0.01
p = 0.005    p = 0.009     p = 0.001
p = 0.06     p = 0.01      p = 0.1
```

and ultimately concatenate them to obtain a 3x3 dataframe structured like this:

```
df3

V1           V2           V3
LFC = 1.2,   LFC = 0.5,   LFC = -0.9,
p = 0.02     p = 0.05     p = 0.01

LFC = 1.5,   LFC = 0.9,   LFC = -1.5
p = 0.005    p = 0.009    p = 0.001

LFC = 0.3,   LFC = 1.1,   LFC = -0.4,
p = 0.06     p = 0.01     p = 0.1
```

What to do here? I appreciate your solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly clear about your expected output but if this is for demonstration purpose you can try :

```
df1[] <- paste0('LFC = ', as.matrix(df1))
df2[] <- paste0('p = ', as.matrix(df2))
df3 <- df2
df3[] <- paste(as.matrix(df1), as.matrix(df2), sep = '\n')
df3

#                    Y1                   Y2                    Y3
#1  LFC = 1.2\np = 0.02  LFC = 0.5\np = 0.05  LFC = -0.9\np = 0.01
#2 LFC = 1.5\np = 0.005 LFC = 0.9\np = 0.009 LFC = -1.5\np = 0.001
#3  LFC = 0.3\np = 0.06  LFC = 1.1\np = 0.01   LFC = -0.4\np = 0.1
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is to paste the prefixes and `Map`, i.e.

```
Map(`rbind`, lapply(df1, function(i)paste0('LFC = ', i)), 
             lapply(df2, function(i) paste0('p = ', i)))
```

which gives,

```
$V1
     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       
[1,] "LFC = 1.2" "LFC = 1.5" "LFC = 0.3"
[2,] "p = 0.02"  "p = 0.005" "p = 0.06" 

$V2
     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       
[1,] "LFC = 0.5" "LFC = 0.9" "LFC = 1.1"
[2,] "p = 0.05"  "p = 0.009" "p = 0.01" 

$V3
     [,1]         [,2]         [,3]        
[1,] "LFC = -0.9" "LFC = -1.5" "LFC = -0.4"
[2,] "p = 0.01"   "p = 0.001"  "p = 0.1"
```

If you want a matrix (or data frame) rather than list, then simply use `mapply` instead of `Map`, i.e.

```
mapply(`rbind`, lapply(df1, function(i)paste0('LFC = ', i)), 
                lapply(df2, function(i) paste0('p = ', i)))

      V1          V2          V3          
[1,] "LFC = 1.2" "LFC = 0.5" "LFC = -0.9"
[2,] "p = 0.02"  "p = 0.05"  "p = 0.01"  
[3,] "LFC = 1.5" "LFC = 0.9" "LFC = -1.5"
[4,] "p = 0.005" "p = 0.009" "p = 0.001" 
[5,] "LFC = 0.3" "LFC = 1.1" "LFC = -0.4"
[6,] "p = 0.06"  "p = 0.01"  "p = 0.1"
```

Also instead of `rbind` you can `paste`, i.e.

```
 mapply(`paste`, lapply(df1, function(i)paste0('LFC = ', i)), 
                 lapply(df2, function(i) paste0('p = ', i)))

     V1                    V2                    V3                    
[1,] "LFC = 1.2 p = 0.02"  "LFC = 0.5 p = 0.05"  "LFC = -0.9 p = 0.01" 
[2,] "LFC = 1.5 p = 0.005" "LFC = 0.9 p = 0.009" "LFC = -1.5 p = 0.001"
[3,] "LFC = 0.3 p = 0.06"  "LFC = 1.1 p = 0.01"  "LFC = -0.4 p = 0.1"
```

Comment: Also: `Map(`rbind`, lapply(df1, function(x) sub("^", "LFC = ", x)), 
    lapply(df2, function(x) sub("^", "p = ", x)))`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but the matrix option returns a 6x3 matrix. If there was a way in this matrix to combine each row with even index to its previous row such that LFC and p values for the same comparison are represented together in a single matrix cell, it would be perfect. Again many thanks!

Comment: @Nimzo Please see edit

Comment: Works perfectly fine now, sthn ugeia mas!

Comment: Hahaha. Na se kala file :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf()`.

```
df3 <- df1
df3[] <- sprintf("LFC = %.1f, p = %.3f", unlist(df1), unlist(df2))

#                     V1                   V2                    V3
# 1 LFC = 1.2, p = 0.020 LFC = 0.5, p = 0.050 LFC = -0.9, p = 0.010
# 2 LFC = 1.5, p = 0.005 LFC = 0.9, p = 0.009 LFC = -1.5, p = 0.001
# 3 LFC = 0.3, p = 0.060 LFC = 1.1, p = 0.010 LFC = -0.4, p = 0.100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works too! It may be some usual regex but could you please explain/provide documentation for the syntax %.1f and %.2f, cause it's first time I see something like this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nimzo it's a C-style string formatting command. `"%f"` means the double precision values. `".1"` means rounding the values to the first number of decimal places. You can search `?sprintf` for more details.